# Count pervious value data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called job order

```
Create table joborder (
   jo_no number,
   jo_date date,
   jo_status char(10)
);

insert into joborder values( 1,'01-03-13','A');
insert into joborder values( 2,'01-03-13','A');
Insert into joborder values (3,'01-03-13','A');
insert into joborder values( 4,'04-03-13','A');
insert into joborder values(5,'08-03-13','B');
insert into joborder values( 6,'12-03-13','C');
```

Status:

- A means Completed
- B means Progress
- C means Dev

I want a report as below.Please don't use the analytical functions because I want this condition to use the basic condition function

```
Date         totalJoborder    A      B     C
---------------------------------------------
01-03-13      3               3      0     0
04-03-13      4               3      1     0
08-03-13      5               3      1     1
12-03-13      6               4      1     1
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is what you need...?

```
WITH job_order AS
         (SELECT 1 jo_no,
                 to_date ('01-03-13', 'dd-mm-yy') jo_date,
                 'A' jo_status
            FROM dual
          UNION ALL
          SELECT 2, to_date ('01-03-13', 'dd-mm-yy'), 'A' FROM dual
          UNION ALL
          SELECT 3, to_date ('01-03-13', 'dd-mm-yy'), 'A' FROM dual
          UNION ALL
          SELECT 4, to_date ('04-03-13', 'dd-mm-yy'), 'A' FROM dual
          UNION ALL
          SELECT 5, to_date ('08-03-13', 'dd-mm-yy'), 'B' FROM dual
          UNION ALL
          SELECT 6, to_date ('12-03-13', 'dd-mm-yy'), 'C' FROM dual),
     my_cte AS
         (  SELECT jo_date,
                   count (jo_status) AS total_job_order,
                   count (CASE jo_status WHEN 'A' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS A,
                   count (CASE jo_status WHEN 'B' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS B,
                   count (CASE jo_status WHEN 'C' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS C
              FROM job_order
          GROUP BY jo_date)
  SELECT c.jo_date,
         (SELECT sum (c1.total_job_order)
            FROM my_cte c1
           WHERE c1.jo_date <= c.jo_date)
             AS total_job_order_2,
         (SELECT sum (c1.a)
            FROM my_cte c1
           WHERE c1.jo_date <= c.jo_date)
             AS a,
         (SELECT sum (c1.b)
            FROM my_cte c1
           WHERE c1.jo_date <= c.jo_date)
             AS b,
         (SELECT sum (c1.c)
            FROM my_cte c1
           WHERE c1.jo_date <= c.jo_date)
             AS c
    FROM my_cte c
ORDER BY c.jo_date;
```

OUTPUT (*on the basis of your sample data*):

```
JO_DATE       TOTAL_JOB_ORDER      A    B    C
1/03/2013     3                    3    0    0
4/03/2013     4                    4    0    0
8/03/2013     5                    4    1    0
12/03/2013    6                    4    1    1
```

Comment: Thanks Rachcha i want this should be in mysql db. and oupt is not as above it should add the previous data as well. like if you see 03/01/2013-3 count and status A and 03/08/2013-1 count but i should show 4 in Total_Job_Order and i should show 3 in A and 1 B

Comment: @Rachcha, please check my above ans. you can avoid writing lot of code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Using PIVOT.

```
 Select jo_date,[A] +[B] +[C] as totalJoborder , [A] ,[B], [C]  from
(
select * from joborder
)as tbl
pivot
(
    count(jo_no) for jo_status in([A],[B],[C])
) as P
```

If your values of A,B,C will be increasing more & are dynamic, then you can use following called as Dynamic PIVOT,

```
Declare @cols varchar(max) = ''
Declare @colsSum varchar(max) = ''
Declare @query varchar(max) = ''

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' +
                        QUOTENAME(Replace(jo_status,char(CAST(0x0016 as int)),'')) val
                      FROM joborder
                      ORDER BY val asc
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                     ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                        , 1, 1, '')
        ,@colsSum = STUFF((SELECT distinct '+' +
                        QUOTENAME(Replace(jo_status,char(CAST(0x0016 as int)),'')) val
                      FROM joborder
                      ORDER BY val asc
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                     ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                        , 1, 1, '') 
Select @cols,@colsSum

SELECT @query =
'SELECT jo_date,' + @cols + ','+ @colsSum  + ' as totalJoborder 
FROM
  joborder
PIVOT 
(
  count(jo_no) 
  FOR jo_status IN( ' + @cols + ' )' +
' ) AS p; '

 execute(@query)
```

For Demo **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1dd63/8)**

Comment: Thanks AK47 i have see the For Demo SQL Fiddle the total number should increment like once date is 3 and second date it should increment values 3+1 =4

Comment: your total number is addition of [A] + [B] + [C] correct?